# Using prepared statements and PDO for protect data

Tags: php, mysql

I need to insert data to a MySQL table via PHP from `<form>`. My primary goal is to discover main rules to protect data, which send from user to server (for example from injections).

So, I'm thinking about using:
- PDO instead mysqli
- prepared statements
I'm a beginner in questions about PHP and Mysql. Am I on the right way? Thanks.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

mysqli_set_charset($connection,"utf8");

if (!$connection)
{
    exit(mysqli_error());
}

$htmlResult = '';

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    $result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $htmlResult = 'Email already taken';
    } else {
        $createUser = $connection->query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('$name', '$phone', '$email', $connection->insert_id)");
        if ($createUser) {
            $htmlResult = 'Ok id is: '.$connection->insert_id;
        }
    }
}

echo $htmlResult;
```

Comment: You can PREPARE statements in MySQLI as well as PDO

Comment: `PDO` & `mySQLi` both offer similar protection through the use of `prepared statements` - the implementations are very different however so it's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: You are pretty far off, and in fact your current code is a good example of what _not_ to do when calling MySQL from PHP.  Please check PHP's documentation on prepared statements.